# Looping through a table ID column, passing that to an URL (JSON), inserting into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would assume that I would use a cursor for this. I understand the concept but never put it into practice at any great length. I have been tasked with pulling data via API from Swagger into SQL Server.

The code works perfectly below if I declare the `@branch` variable but I am very resisted to the lazy approach by copying the code 17 times and changing the `@branch` variable to insert into a table as I would like the automate the process for the future when new branches come onboard

I have a table called `dbo.branches` that looks like this:

[image: branch_example]

The code mentioned above that works perfectly is this

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @hr AS INT

DECLARE @json AS TABLE (Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @URL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @branch AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @shortname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @api_key AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @start_date AS DATE
DECLARE @offset AS INT
DECLARE @count AS INT

SET @api_key = '123456'
SET @shortname = 'abcd'
SET @branch = '0004-888c'
SET @offset = 0
SET @start_date = convert(char(10),getdate()-90,126)
SET @count = 1000
SET @URL= CONCAT('https://*************/',@shortname,'/********?branchID=',@branch,'&startDate=',@start_date,'&offset=',@offset,'&count=',@count,'&api_key=',@api_key)

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',@URL,'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) 
   EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'

SELECT * FROM @json

INSERT INTO dbo.mortgages
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json), N'$.Data')
    WITH 
        ([Amount] DECIMAL(8,2) N'$.Amount',
         [Borrower_Account_Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.BorrowerAccountName',
         [Created_At] DATETIME2 N'$.CreatedAt',
         [Extra_Notes] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.ExtraNotes',
         [Interest_Rate] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.IntrestRate',
         [Market_Value] DECIMAL(8,2) N'$.MarketValue',
         [Monthly_Payment] DECIMAL(5,2) N'$.MonthlyPayment',
         [Mortgage_Account_Number] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.MortgageAccountNumber',
         [Mortgage_Provider] NVARCHAR(100)  N'$.MortgageProvider',
         [Property_Ownable_ID] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.PropertyOwnableID',
         [Sales_Instruction_ID] NVARCHAR(5) N'$.SalesInstructionID',
         [Type] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.Type',
         [Valuation_Date] DATETIME2  N'$.ValuationDate'
    )
```

What I would like to achieve is that the OID from dbo.branches passes to the @branch which will complete the @URL, loop through to insert the JSON output into the dbo.mortgages for each OID in the dbo.branches

i have also had in my cranium that i will need a row_number within dbo.branches so when it does loop through it knows when to stop?

many thanks for any help!

Comment: You could stuff the entire thing inside a stored procedure and just feed it the `@branch` variable on each execute.... Then you only copy a single row each time.

Comment: Make certain you want to continue using `sp_OACreate`? These are generally unavailable on any locked down system. Also _never_ use an `insert` without a column list. As @ZoharPeled mentioned, the first step is to turn this into a stored procedure that takes branch as a parameter

Comment: Great idea on the stored procedure. Will have a go at as it makes sense to